# Enterprise Database Workflow with Online Mapping

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, web-service, versioning

We bought a trimble units for our operators to collect data out in the field using Collector. We currently have ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 with SQL Server 2012 setup on one of our servers. Our server manager has been federated with portal and all of our data has been versioned. All of our layers currently have the Z & M values turned on.

From what I've read and tested these values will not work for the online mapping use.

Do I have to recreate the database and each layer without Z and M Values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with an Esri Analysis and explaining our situation we ended up recreating the geodatabase and migrating the data to new geodatabase without these 2 values. Everything is working fine.